# How to create a branch and reset another with git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am working on a project on GitHub. On my computer I made six commits that I have not yet pushed to the GitHub server. Now I realize that I want to keep the current `master` branch that is in the cloud, and put the commits in a separate branch called `development`. How can I do this? I am new to Git and GitHub.

EDIT: I also have a few commits that *have* been pushed to GitHub from before the unpushed commits. I want to keep these in both branches, whie only keeping the unpushed commits in `development`.

Comment: In the end, do you want to continue on "development" or on "master". -- The answer to that question slightly changes the "best command line strategy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new branch where you are called `development`:

```
git branch development
```

Then move master to where it is on the remote:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now `development` points to your last commit while `master` is where it was before the commits.

You can push the new branch and set up remote tracking (so push and pull work with no additional arguments) with

```
git push -u origin development
```

Comment: I have also committed several times that I _have_ pushed to GitHub. Wouldn't `git reset --hard origin/master` reset all of my commits? I only want the six unpushed commits to be reset in the `master` branch, but saved and pushed in the `development` branch.

Comment: No. That reset will make master point to whatever you pushed to the remote called origin last

Comment: Reset in general just moves the tip of the current branch around. It doesn't really remove changes or anything like that.

Comment: git does not delete history in general without some very specific instructions. In fact, even if you were to reset master before saving the new branch, you could recover the commits with `git reflog`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is create a branch at the point where you are and "be" on it. `git checkout` is the only command which can change the current branch. And its `-b` option creates a branch on top (at the point you are at the moment, if you don't tell it otherwise):

```
git checkout -b development
```

Then you want to set local branch `master` back to where the remote is. This you do by setting it to the so-called "local remote-tracking branch", which is a snapshot of the remote branch (from the time of last fetch/push):

```
git branch --force master origin/master
```

You have to use `--force` here, because otherwise `git branch` will not change existing branches.

Comment: Why do you need to check out the new branch, especially if your immediate next step is to work with another branch?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is the intention not to continue on the `development` branch? The `git branch` command does not change the current checkout as your comment might suggest.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have made the commits to your `local` master branch; create a new branch in local and call that development

```
git branch development
git checkout development
```

your commits would be there in this new branch and you can push to cloud aka remote in git world

```
git push origin development
```

please make sure you are **not** doing

```
 git push origin master
```

if so the remote/cloud master would have your commits; which I believe you don't need

Comment: How is OP going to reset master to what it is on the server?